# Typescript get the correct type based on an action type

Tags: typescript

I have the following function that takes a `params` object with unique action:

```
enum Actions {
  A,
  B
}

interface Action {
  name: string;
  action: Actions;
}

interface ActionOne extends Action {
  action: Actions.A,
  payload: {
    a: number;
  }
}

interface ActionTwo extends Action {
  action: Actions.B,
  payload: {
    a: number;
    b: string;
  }
}


function startAction(params: ActionOne)
function startAction(params: ActionTwo);
function startAction(params: Action) {
  switch (params.action) {
    case Actions.A:
      params. // I want autocomplete based on the type
      return;
    case Actions.B:
      params. // I want autocomplete based on the type
      return;
  }
}

startAction({ name: '', action: Actions.A, payload: { a: 1 } });
startAction({ name: '', action: Actions.B, payload: {a: 1, b: 'ds'} })
```

When I call the `startAction` method, I'm getting the correct autocomplete based on the passed `action`. But, inside the `switch` case, I don't have the power of the autocomplete. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if `action === Actions.A`, that's not enough to ensure that the type `params` is actually `ActionOne`. The compiler can't be sure that there's not some other action defined like this elsewhere in your application:

```
interface ActionThree extends Action {
  action: Actions.A,
  payload: {
    foo: string;
  }
}
```

You need to convice the compiler that your switch statement is exhaustive. Try writing your final function signature like this:

```
function startAction(params: ActionOne | ActionTwo) {
  ...
}
```